# Update existing data in Firebase (Swift)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**Firebase Data Structure:**

```
users
       - 90384m590v834dfgok34
          •userName: "Matt"
          •values: ["test1", "test2"]
```

I am wanting to update the values inside of these firebase entries without replacing the whole thing. I know the update() function is what I need to do, but from the example I tried it is not working.

Also, how would I append a new item to the values array through the update() function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a reference for the user whose values you'd like to update and use `updateChildValues`.

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users/90384m590v834dfgok34")

ref.updateChildValues([
    "values": [
        "test3",
        "test4"
    ]
])
```

Comment: FIRDatabase has been renamed to Database